# On defining sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can two infinite sequences be "concatenated"? Two examples:

\begin{align*}
S &= (2,4,6,8,10\ldots,1,3,5,7,9\ldots)\\
\\
T &= (2,3,7,13,19,\ldots,5,11,17,23\ldots)
\end{align*}

My hunch is no. The only reason I can provide at the moment is that it would be impossible to establish a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and the terms of the sequence.

A related question I have is about this "concatenation operator". Is that defined anywhere? It's reminiscent of union. But the concatenation of two countable sequences as above would be uncountable then, wouldn't it?

**A thank you to everyone (except one commentator) who provided me with clarifications, hints, leads, and links to further reading.**

Comment: How exactly is this sequence supposed to be defined? $3,7,13,19$ seems to denote the $2n+1$-th prime, but since there are infinitely many primes, it's not clear where in the sequence, e.g., 5 would come up. Unless you are talking about some kind of transfinite sequence, what you propose is not well-defined.

Comment: If infinitely many numbers precede $5$, then this is not a sequence in the conventional sense. However, "going to $\infty$" and starting again can be a very useful device.

Comment: It is unclear how this is defined - eg why $2$ is where it is. On the other hand the Sharkovsky ordering http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Sharkovsky_ordering may be of interest. This kind of concept is best described as an ordering rather than a sequence.

Comment: @AndréNicolas "going to ∞ and starting again can be a very useful device". Go on... Is this have anything to do with transfinite sequences mentioned by Johannes?

Comment: @sasha: Yes. The idea was discovered by Cantor, when he was studying derived sets of derived sets of $\dots$. It is continuing the notion of sequence beyond the ordinal $\omega$.

Comment: Transfinite sequences are very common. The example you suggest is indexed by what set theorists usually call $\omega+\omega$. There are much more complicated possibilities, of course, and the fact that you are only listing primes really does not matter much, as long as the index set is countable. But we can also have larger, uncountable index sets. (So no, you are not the first.) These indices are more than a curiosity, by the way, and prove quite useful in many situations. Cantor was the first to consider them seriously.

Comment: The concatenation of two ordinary sequences is still a countable (generalized) sequence. Assuming that the terms of the concatenated sequence are all distinct, you can still establish a bijection between them and $\Bbb N$; it just won’t list them in the concatenated order. You might be interested in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) and [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic) in Wikipedia.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks, meta-question: why do all you power-users put the good suggestions, answers in the comments, where I can't accept them!? (To give others a chance?)

Comment: @sasha: I’ve been making a concerted effort to make mine answers rather than comments, if only to reduce the number of questions without answers. I wanted to post a longer answer to this, but I didn’t see it until after it was put on hold. I don’t understand what’s unclear about it, and I’ve put in a request to have it re-opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, primes are really irrelevant: what you’re interested in here is the notion of concatenating two ordinary infinite sequences to produce a longer sequence-like object. As several people noted in the comments, this is entirely possible, and the resulting sequence-like objects (and others even longer and more complicated) are very useful in some parts of mathematics; set theory and some areas of general and set-theoretic topology come to mind.

These objects are sometimes called *transfinite sequences*. Just as ordinary sequences are typically indexed by elements of $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb Z^+$, these more general sequences are typically indexed by [*ordinals*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number). Ordinary sequences are indexed by the ordinal $\omega=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$, which you can identify with $\Bbb N$ if you like. Your concatenated sequences are indexed by the ordinal $\omega+\omega$, which ‘looks like’ two copies of $\omega$ strung end to end:

$$0,1,2,3,\ldots,n,\ldots,\omega,\omega+1,\omega+2,\omega+3,\ldots,\omega+n,\ldots\;,$$

or pictorially $\longrightarrow\longrightarrow$. If you concatenated three ordinary sequences, you’d get something indexed by $\omega+\omega+\omega$; an example is

$$0,3,6,9,\ldots,3n,\ldots,1,4,7,10,\ldots,3n+1,\ldots,2,5,8,11,\ldots,3n+2,\ldots\;,\tag{1}$$

indexed by

$$0,1,2,\ldots,n,\ldots,\omega,\omega+1,\omega+2,\ldots,\omega+n,\ldots,\omega+\omega,\omega+\omega+1,\omega+\omega+2,\ldots\;.$$

All of these generalized sequences are still countable. In the case of the simple concatenation of two ordinary sequences you actually demonstrated that in your original post: the fact that you can take the countably infinite set $\Bbb N$ (or $\omega$) and rearrange it as

$$0,2,4,6,\ldots,1,3,5,7,\ldots$$

shows that this concatenated ‘sequence’ is still countable. My example $(1)$ shows that the same is true of the generalized sequence obtained by concatenating three ordinary sequences.

You might be interested in a simple example of a generalized sequence that looks like a whole sequence of sequences concatenated together. Define an order $\preceq$ on $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ as follows: for $\langle k,\ell\rangle,\langle m,n\rangle\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$, $\langle k,\ell\rangle\preceq\langle m,n\rangle$ if and only if either $k<m$, or $k=m$ and $\ell\le n$. (This is the so-called [*lexicographic order*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) (or *dictionary order*) on $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$.) If you play with the order a bit, you’ll see that it looks like this:

$$\begin{align*}
&\langle 0,0\rangle\prec\langle 0,1\rangle\prec\langle 0,2\rangle\prec\langle 0,3\rangle\prec\ldots\\
&\langle 1,0\rangle\prec\langle 1,1\rangle\prec\langle 1,2\rangle\prec\langle 1,3\rangle\prec\ldots\\
&\langle 2,0\rangle\prec\langle 2,1\rangle\prec\langle 2,2\rangle\prec\langle 2,3\rangle\prec\ldots\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\vdots
\end{align*}$$

Arranged horizontally, with each ordinary sequence (i.e., each line of the display above) represented by an arrow, that’s $\longrightarrow\longrightarrow\longrightarrow\cdots$. And this is still a countable generalized sequence, since I can rearrange $\Bbb Z^+$ into such a generalized sequence:

$$\begin{align*}
&1,3,5,7,9,11,\ldots\\
&2,6,10,14,18,22,\ldots\\
&4,12,20,28,36,44,\ldots\\
&8,24,40,56,72,88,\ldots\\
&\qquad\qquad\vdots
\end{align*}$$

Here the $n$-th row contains the numbers divisible by $2^{n-1}$ but not by $2^n$.

The Wikipedia articles on [well-orders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order), [ordinals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number), and [ordinal arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic) are a place to start getting some idea of these matters, though if you really get interested, you’ll probably want to look at a serious introductory set theory text; I like Karel Hrbacek & Thomas Jech, [*Introduction to Set Theory, Third Edition, Revised and Expanded*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824779150), which is written for advanced undergraduates and first-year graduate students. (The first two editions lack some of the newer material in this edition, but they’re still fine introductions.)

Comment: What an enlightening response, thank you!

Comment: @sasha: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can partition the primes into two subsets if you wish, though you should not write it like that if you want to be clear.

One possibility might be primes not of the form $6n-1$ and the other of primes of the form $6n-1$.  If that is your pattern, then it has been done before: see [OEIS A045331](http://oeis.org/A045331) and [A007528](http://oeis.org/A007528)

Comment: " though you should not write it like that if you want to be clear." I don't understand why.

Comment: Because it is unclear what "$2,3,7,13,19,\ldots,5,11,17,23\ldots$" is supposed to mean without more information, while saying "$2,3,7,13,19,\ldots$ and $5,11,17,23\ldots$" has natural interpretations such as two sequences or two sets

Comment: Understood! Thanks. But just for the sake of argument, is it really unclear? You seemed to understand what I was asking about (the two subsets). Doesn't the ellipsis indicate the pattern continues in the manner expressed by the initial terms, then the appended second sequence does the same?